# How to format a CSV data with str values to float values by reading it?

Tags: python, csv, format

This is how the CSV looks like

[image]

and python after using the code

```
def get_returns(file):
    return pd.read_csv(file + ".csv", index_col = 0, parse_dates = True).pct_change()
#example
df= get_returns("SP500")
```

shows up with folloiwng error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

With this formating data there is no problem (other web source, other dataset)

For sure i could format it first in excel before reading it but on longterm that could be annyoing.

[image]

Comment: use the dtypes argument in the pd.read_csv call

Comment: you mean like this? def get_returns(file):
    return pd.read_csv(file + ".csv", index_col = 0, parse_dates = True,dtype={"Open": float,
                                                                              "High":float,
                                                                               "Low":float,
                                                                               "Close":float}).pct_change()

Comment: yes, I think that will work

Comment: at least it does not show up this error anymore..so i think this is solved :) but now another error arise  values = data.pop(self.index_col[i])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I'd recommend breaking this out into a couple different lines. Will make it easier to debug. I think this issue is now with the pct_change call, but can't be certain now since it all happens on one line.

Comment: @user1558604 thanks! Could solve it subsequently all within my self response to this Question. Thanks on your impact :)

Answer (score 0):

got clarified in total to avoid

a)

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
```

and then b)

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

this solved it all

```
def get_returns(file):
    dfcolumns = pd.read_csv(file + ".csv",nrows=1)
    return pd.read_csv(file + ".csv", index_col = 0, parse_dates = True,dtype={"Open": float,
                                                                              "High":float,
                                                                               "Low":float,
                                                                               "Close":float},usecols = list(range(len(dfcolumns.columns)))).pct_change()
```

BUT! Before in Excel i had to change the date xx/xx/xx to xx-xx-xx  & "" by using search and replace to nothing